# find() vs findOne() with for loop for retrieving all

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, optimization

Is there any speed/use/readability difference between `find()` vs `findOne()` with for loop if i want to retrieve all documents?

I want to make my code more reusable, and i have code which is populating my blog Post with and Author, but now I have to populate it in two different places, in homePage controller **(shows all posts, uses `find()`)** and in single post controller **(`findOne()`)**

Comment: repetitive `findOne` means firing multiple db calls, which will have significant performance impact. You should choose a single `find` over multiple `findOne` from performance consideration.

Comment: I think find was replaced with findOne and findMany by Mongo team to be more explicit. If you would like to retrieve many documents most performant way of doing this will surely be using findMany or find but I would suggest using findMany.